# Django Foreign Key limit_choice_to with model object filter

Tags: python, django-models, django-rest-framework, foreign-keys, limit-choices-to

I'm trying to limit the choices for a foreign key in my django admin tool. I stumbled across the `limit_choices_to` option for the `ForeignKey` model: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to

In my models, I have a `Question_logic` that has an attribute `ifLogic` which is a foreign key of the model `Options` (which represent the possible answers of options of a question).

```py
# Models.py

class Options(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    option = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Question_logic(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
# error here:
    ifLogic = models.ForeignKey(Options, on_delete=models.CASCADE, limit_choices_to=Options.objects.filter(question=question))
    thenLogic = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

However this approach does not work because apparently you can't reference an object in the model definition itself and I'm getting this error:

```
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.
```

My logic is quite straightforward: I want the admin to chose only between the options that are relevant for the specific question. How do I implement this correctly?

Thanks.

Comment: This does not work, `limit_choices` to can only work with a `Q` object or a dictionary. Not a `QuerySet` (and definitely not one filtered by another field). You will need to implement the logic in the form.

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: @FabioMagarelli You need to set the form fields `queryset` by overriding your forms `__init__` method.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that I'm using Django Rest Framework

Comment: @FabioMagarelli: then you need to do this with the serializer, but you can *not* do this with `limit_choices_to`.

Comment: How do I do that? also consider that `question` when you create a new instance of `Question_logic` is always null until you pick a question

Answer (score 1):

Foreign key choices in the admin can be limited via [ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey). During form instantiation, the current object (i.e. `QuestionLogic`) is stored on the request object that is available in the `formfield_for_foreignkey()` method.

Note that the object is not stored on the ModelAdmin object because that is not thread-safe.

```
class QuestionLogicAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs)
        # Store Question object on request for later retrieval.
        request._obj_ = obj 

        return super().get_form(request, question, **kwargs)
        
    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "ifLogic" and request._obj_:
            question = request._obj_.question
            kwargs["queryset"] = Options.objects.filter(question=question)
```

PS: In Python, it is good practice to use CapitalizedWords naming convention for class names (i.e. QuestionLogic instead of Question_logic). Instance variables should be lowercase with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability (i.e. `if_logic` instead of `ifLogic`). You can read up on that in the [PEP8 styleguide](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/).